# no lee después de ejecutar los subprocesos - java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa en java, una simulación de un menú de compra, aún no imprime el resultado porque aún no lo agrego, pero este no es el caso, cuando lo ejecuto todo funciona bien, pero después cuando se ejecuta la pregunta (desea seleccionar otro producto mas? si/no) debería leer la variable que sigue, pero se salta ese paso.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prueba{

    public Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
    public double cantidad, total[];    
    public int producto = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prueba p = new prueba();
        String menu[] = new String[4], eleccion;
        boolean continuar = true;

        System.out.println("ingrese el numero de producto que desea llevar");
        menu[0] = "---------------------------------";
        menu[1] = "1. Tablet lenovo MAM..... $395.99";
        menu[2] = "2. Windows 11............ $159.75";
        menu[3] = "3. Impresora Laser....... $377.55";

        //eleccion = p.t.nextLine();
        //mostrar menú
        while(continuar==true){
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            System.out.println(menu[i]);
        }

        //llamado de los SubProcesos
        p.eleccionProducto();
        menu[p.producto] = "";
        p.cantidadProducto();

        System.out.println("desea seleccionar otro producto mas? si/no");

        eleccion = p.t.nextLine();

        if(eleccion.equals("si")){
        } else{
            continuar = false;
        }
    }

   }
```

el programa, después de llamar a los dos subprocesos, eleccionProducto y cantidadProducto por alguna razón hace que no me lea la línea que sigue de `eleccion = p.t.nextLine()` no me lee nada, si quito el llamado de esos dos subprocesos si me lee la variable elección.

```
   public void eleccionProducto(){

        while(producto!=1 && producto!=2 && producto!=3){
            producto = t.nextInt();
            if(producto<1&&producto>3){
                System.out.println("opcion invalida, ingrese una de las opciones de la lista");
            }
        }
   }

   public void cantidadProducto(){
        System.out.println("cantidad a llevar: ");
        cantidad = t.nextInt();
        total = new double[3];

            switch(producto){

            case 1:
            total[0] = 395.99*cantidad;
            break;

            case 2:
            total[1] = 159.75*cantidad;
            break;

            case 3:
            total[2] = 377.55*cantidad;
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se ingresan datos por consola, estos datos se guardan en un espacio de memoria temporal denominado buffer.

Al finalizar de ingresar un dato, se presiona la tecla Enter, la cual también es almacenada en el buffer como un salto de línea ‘\n’, junto con los datos.

El método nextLine ( ) extrae del buffer todos los caracteres que encuentra hasta llegar al Enter, el cual es eliminado del buffer.

Los métodos nextInt ( ) y nextDouble ( ) extraen el dato numérico, lo asignan a la variable, pero dejan el ‘\n’, que es lo único que queda al final en el buffer.

Cuando se invoca nextLine ( ) después de cualquiera de los dos métodos anteriores, lo que ocurre es que como en el buffer hay aún un dato (el ‘\n’), lo procesa inmediatamente como se describió antes, es decir, lee los caracteres hasta encontrar el ‘\n’, pero como ya no hay caracteres antes del ‘\n’, no lee ninguno, a continuación elimina el ‘\n’ y finalmente a la variable se le asigna la cadena vacía.

Una solución, utilizando un único objeto Scanner, es invocar nextLine(); después del ingreso del dato numérico y antes del ingreso de la cadena, para que de esta manera dicha sentencia elimine el ‘\n’ y el buffer quede vacío antes de leer la cadena.

```
System.out.println("desea seleccionar otro producto mas? si/no");
        p.t.nextLine();
        eleccion = p.t.nextLine();
```