# Error con menú switch

Tags: java

en resumen, si escojo la opción 3. Okey, funciona. Pero al elegir la opción 1 y 2, posteriormente me imprime "mensaje" y "clave" seguido. Sin opción a dejarme escribir correctamente el Scanner.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Practica_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //Scanner para el programa
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Aqui añadiremos la palabra finalmente codifica o decodificada
        
        String mensajeBis = "";
        
        //Distintas variables
        
        int eleccion,clave;
        
        int código, códigoBis;
        
        char caracterBis, caracterM;
            
        String mensaje;

        boolean salir = false;
        
        //ciclo hasta cumplir condición.
        
        do { //Imprimimos distintas opciones para el usuario
            System.out.println("¿Que quieres hacer?");
            System.out.println("1. CODIFICAR");
            System.out.println("2. DESCODIFICAR");
            System.out.println("3. SALIR");
            
            System.out.print("Ingrese una opción: ");
            eleccion= sc.nextInt();
            
            switch(eleccion)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Está en la opción 1");
                
                
                System.out.println("Introduzca un mensaje: ");
                
                mensaje = sc.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Introduzca una clave: ");
                                    
                clave = sc.nextInt();
                
                for (int i=0; i< mensaje.length(); i++) {
                    caracterM = mensaje.charAt(i);
                    código=(int)mensaje.charAt(i); 
                        
                        

                        //Printeamos que el código (num) equivale a un caracter del mensaje.
                        System.out.println("El código  " + código + "  equivale a  " + " * " + caracterM + " * " );
                                
                        códigoBis= código+clave;  //en el caso de descodificar, que es esta linea que constituye a restar la clave.
                        
                        //Printeamos la operación de la clave al código.
                        System.out.println("Al código le sumamos o restamos la clave y quedaria " + códigoBis);
                                        
                        caracterBis=(char)códigoBis;
                        
                        //Se convierte a caracter el resultado de la operación.
                        System.out.println("El códigoBis se convierte a carácter " + caracterBis);
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    
                        mensajeBis+=(char)códigoBis;}
                    
                System.out.println("El mensaje original es: " + mensaje);
                    
                    
                System.out.println("La clave cambiada es: " + mensajeBis);  
                
                break;
                
                
            case 2:
                
                System.out.println("Está en la opción 2");

                System.out.println("Introduzca un mensaje: ");
                
                mensaje = sc.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Introduzca una clave: ");
                                    
                clave = sc.nextInt();
                
                for (int i=0; i< mensaje.length(); i++) {
                    caracterM = mensaje.charAt(i);
                    código=(int)mensaje.charAt(i); 

                        //Printeamos que el código (num) equivale a un caracter del mensaje.
                        System.out.println("El código  " + código + "  equivale a  " + " * " + caracterM + " * " );
                                
                        códigoBis= código-clave;  //en el caso de descodificar, que es esta linea que constituye a restar la clave.
                        
                        //Printeamos la operación de la clave al código.
                        System.out.println("Al código le sumamos o restamos la clave y quedaria " + códigoBis);
                                        
                        caracterBis=(char)códigoBis;
                        
                        //Se convierte a caracter el resultado de la operación.
                        System.out.println("El códigoBis se convierte a carácter " + caracterBis);
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    
                        mensajeBis+=(char)códigoBis;}
                    
                System.out.println("El mensaje original es: " + mensaje);
                    
                    
                System.out.println("La clave cambiada es: " + mensajeBis);  
                
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("HA SALIDO DEL PROGRAMA");
                salir=true;
                break;
                
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese un dato correcto");
            }
            
        } while (!salir);
        
        

    } 
    
}
```

Si también me dais algún consejo para que quede más "minimalista" y entendible lo agradezco. No se si es por el orden de algun elemento que se me esté pasando y demás. Le he estado dando una vuelta y tal vez , más que orden haya un elemento que no tenga del todo claro su correcto funcionamiento y esté "chocando". De cualquier forma...

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: lo que sucede [es lo siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487951/no-lee-despu%c3%a9s-de-ejecutar-los-subprocesos-java/487979#487979)

Comment: un consejo importa solo las librerías que vas a usar , en el caso de tu código solo SCANNER

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione básicamente es cambiar esta linea en los casos 1 y 2:

```
mensaje = sc.nextLine();
```

La cambias a:

```
mensaje = sc.next();
```

Y ya me ha funcionado.